# How can a Dapp store seed keys of non-HD wallets?(tumbleweed)

Tags: optimization

As the title suggests, is there a Dapp that exists to store seed keys of wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Since the content of the blockchain is public, you do not want to store secret keys on the blockchain as anyone running an Ethereum node would be able to read the keys.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it of course but no one wants to do it as you know on blockchain everything happens in the form of transaction and all the transactions are public on ethereum, mean everyone would be able to access your seed keys